# Post comments on a WordPress page from Android application

Tags: android, http, wordpress

I need to post some text to a remote server over HTTP, this server in turn puts these comment on a Wordpress page. I am still waiting for interface details.

Is it possible to post comments directly on a Wordpress page from an Android or Java application?

Links to relevant documentation, tutorials etc. is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [one Java client library for WordPress](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/). A Google search will probably turn up others -- after all, that's where I got the one linked to above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. I am not developing a full-fledged Wordpress client; I just need the "add a new comment" functionality in my app. Wouldn't adding the full library be too much?
I did some googling myself and found that wordpress has exposed their APIs  to be consumed using XML-RPC protocol(details http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp#wp.newComment). If I could somehow invoke this method using DefaultHttpClient, I should be good I think.

Comment: "Wouldn't adding the full library be too much?" Beats me -- I didn't look at the size. I'll be a bit surprised if you find a library that only does comments, though. "If I could somehow invoke this method using DefaultHttpClient, I should be good I think." -- XML-RPC is certainly simpler than SOAP. I have hand-crafted XML-RPC payloads in the past, though not real recently. The Apache XML-RPC client might work on Android as well.

Comment: "XML-RPC is certainly simpler than SOAP. I have hand-crafted XML-RPC payloads in the past, though not real recently"  I skimmed through the XML-RPC specs [http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec] and tried to hand-craft a request myself for invoking wp.newComment(link in comments above). Not sure if I've got it right, though. :|
"A Google search will probably turn up others..."
The Wikipedia entry for XML-RPC enlists lots of client libraries under Java including some of which you've already mentioned.